# Factorization of the trinomial $x^{2n}+Dx^n+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

The following trinomials will factor for any $a$,

$$1+a(-3+a^2)x^3+x^6 = (1+ax+x^2)(1-ax-x^2+a^2x^2-ax^3+x^4)\tag{1}$$

and similarly for,

$$1+a(5-5a^2+a^4)x^5+x^{10}\tag{2}$$

$$1+a(-7+14a^2-7a^4+a^6)x^7+x^{14}\tag{3}$$

$$1+a(9-30a^2+27a^4-9a^6+a^8)x^9+x^{18}\tag{4}$$

and so on. (The second one is notable in that for general $a$ it has two factors, but if $a$ is an even-index [*Lucas number*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number), then there is a third factor.)

***Questions***:

1. Given $P(x) = x^{2n}+Dx^n+1$ for all ODD $n>1$, is there a general formula for $D$ as a polynomial in $a$ such that $(1+ax+x^2)$ is a factor of $P(x)$?
2. The fourth generally has 3 factors. Is there an odd $n$ such that $P(x)$ generally has *four* factors?

Comment: Could you give us a hint about what those polynomials in $a$ are?  What does "and so on" mean?

Comment: They parameterize $D$. For example, let $a=3$ then $x^6+18x^3+1$ will factor.

Comment: Are you factoring over integers?  Are you suggesting that if $D$ is not of the form $a(-3+a^2)$, then $1+Dx^3+x^6$ will not factor?     If $D$ *is* of that form, you are claiming that $1+Dx^3+x^6$ will factor; why?  Your question is difficult for me to understand.

Comment: @vadim123: It means there is one for $x^{22}+Dx^{11}+1$, etc as well, but it is too tedious to write them all. I am interested if there a general formula for $D$.

Comment: @vadim123: We can limit it over the integers if that makes the problem simpler.

Comment: You ask "for all odd $n$", so what is the example when $n = 1$? Also, it would be helpful if you included the parametric factorizations (with $a$ in the factorization, not just a special case like $a = 3$). That would be analogous to the universal factorization $x^2 - a^2 = (x-a)(x+a)$.

Comment: And if you already know a parametric formula for $D$, as you indicate in your reply to vadim123, then what exactly do you want to know from your first question?

Comment: I know a parametric formula for $n = 11,13$ and a few more higher $n$ but I am only _assuming_ the process works for ALL odd $n > 1$.

Comment: @KCd: Fair enough, I'll limit it to $n > 1$.

Comment: Your examples are all "rigged" so that $x^2+ax+1$ is a factor. This universal factor should be indicated in the body of the question.

Comment: @KCd: Fair enough. That factor has been indicated in the body of the first question.

Comment: @vadim123: The polynomial $D$ is the $n$th Chebyshev polynomial. See my answer below.

Comment: @Kcd, you are Sherlock Holmes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we work in ${\mathbf Z}[x,a]/(x^2+ax+1)$, with $a$ and $x$ as independent indeterminates then we seek a polynomial $D_n$ in ${\mathbf Z}[a]$ such that $x^{2n}+D_nx^n+1 \equiv 0 \bmod x^2+ax+1$ for odd $n$.

Starting from $x^2 \equiv -ax-1 \bmod x^2+ax+1$ we can compute higher powers of $x$ to that modulus by using this relation for $x^2$, for instance $x^3 \equiv (a^2-1)x+a \bmod x^2+ax+1$ and $x^4 \equiv (-a^3+2a)x + (-a^2+1) \bmod x^2+ax+1$. In general, define polynomials $f_n(a)$ and $g_n(a)$ in ${\mathbf Z}[a]$ to fit 
$$
x^n \equiv f_n(a)x + g_n(a) \bmod x^2+ax+1.
$$
Then square both sides and use the reduction formula for $x^2 \bmod x^2+ax+1$ to get 
$$
x^{2n} \equiv (2f_n(a)g_n(a)-af_n(a)^2)x + (g_n(a)^2-f_n(a)^2) \bmod x^2+ax+1, 
$$
so for an unknown $D$ in ${\mathbf Z}[a]$, we have 
$$
x^{2n} + Dx^n + 1 \equiv (f_n(a)D - af_n(a)^2 + 2f_n(a)g_n(a))x + (g_n(a)^2-f_n(a)^2+ g_n(a)D+1).
$$
We want this to be $0 \bmod x^2+ax+1$, so we want to find $D$ satisfying the following two equations:
$$
f_n(a)D = af_n(a)^2 - 2f_n(a)g_n(a), \ \ \ g_n(a)D = f_n(a)^2 - g_n(a)^2 -1
$$
in ${\mathbf Z}[a]$. From the first equation, the obvious choice to make is 
$$
D = af_n(a) - 2g_n(a).
$$
Testing this with $n = 3, 5, 7, 9$ already recovers the coefficient of $x^n$ for these $n$ in your question, so we're clearly on the right track.
We also need to have this $D$ fit the second condition above, and that is the same as 
$$
g_n(a)(af_n(a)-2g_n(a)) \stackrel{?}{=} f_n(a)^2-g_n(a)^2+1,
$$
or equivalently 
$$
f_n(a)^2+g_n(a)^2 = af_n(a)g_n(a) - 1.
$$
I leave it as an exercise to check the coefficients of $x^n \bmod x^2+ax+1$ satisfy this constraint.

Edit:  This calculation makes no distinction between even $n$ and odd $n$. It works for all $n$. For instance, when $n = 2$ and $n = 4$ the corresponding trinomials would be $x^4 + (-a^2+2)x^2 + 1$ and $x^6 + (a^3-3a)x^3 + 1$. Once I saw those I realized that in fact the coefficient of $x^n$ for all $n$ is a *normalized* $n$th Chebyshev polynomial up to a sign. Writing $a^n + 1/a^n = T_n(a + 1/a)$, we have $T_1(a) = a$, $T_2(a) = a^2 - 2$, $T_3(a) = a^3 - 3a$, $T_4(a) = a^4 - 4a^2 + 2$, and $T_5(a) = a^5 - 5a^3 + 5a$. Then your examples are simply $x^{2n}+(-1)^{n-1}T_n(a)x^n+1$.  So your task amounts to showing $x^{2n}+(-1)^{n-1}T_n(a)x^n+1 \equiv 0 \bmod x^2+ax+1$ for all $n \geq 1$.

In ${\mathbf Z}[a,x]/(x^2+ax+1)$, $x$ is a unit (with inverse ($-x-a$)) and $x + 1/x = -a$. In this ring \begin{eqnarray*}x^{2n} + (-1)^{n-1}T_n(a)x^n + 1 & = & x^n(x^n + 1/x^n + (-1)^{n-1}T_n(a)) \\ & = & x^n(T_n(x+1/x) + (-1)^{n-1}T_n(a)) \\ & = & x^n(T_n(-a) + (-1)^{n-1}T_n(a)).\end{eqnarray*}
Since $T_n(-a) = (-1)^nT_n(a)$, the sum $T_n(-a) + (-1)^{n-1}T_n(a)$ is 0, and that proves $x^{2n} + (-1)^{n-1}T_n(a)x^n + 1 \equiv 0 \bmod x^2 + ax + 1$ for all $n \geq 1$ (including even $n$).

Comment: Thanks,KCd! I knew there had to be a general formula. The polynomial $a^6-7a^4+14a^2-7$ looked familiar to me, and of course it is the minimal polynomial for $2\cos(\pi/14)$ but as you pointed out the Chebyshev polynomials are more appropriate. (And regarding my second question, it turns out for $n=15$, then $P(x)$ has four factors.)

Comment: Since the case $n=15$ usually has 4 factors as a varies, which one also sees for $n=6$, the typical number of irreducible factors for $x^{2}n+(-1)^{n-1}T_n(a)x^n+1$ as a runs through $\mathbf Z$ should presumably depend on the prime factorization of $n$. After some numerical experimenting, I'd suggest that the number of irreducible factors is $d(n)$ = the number of (positive) factors of $n$. More precisely, as a polynomial in 2 variables $x^{2n}+(-1)^{n-1}T_n(a)x^n+1$ probably has $d(n)$ irreducible factors in ${\mathbf Z}[x,a]$. This is 4 iff $n=p^3$ or $pq$ ($p, q$ distinct primes).